# xpath to check '@' present

Tags: xpath

I want to write xpath to check node contain '@'

```
<node1>
<node11>Some text</node11>
<node11>@2o11 PickMe</node12>
</node1>
```

I want to write xpath like "//node11[contains(,'@\d+')]". Whats correct way to check @

Answer (score 0):

The correct XPath expression is:

```
//node11[contains(., '@')]
```

In your XML, the closing tag of the second subnote should be `</node11>` instead of `</node12>`.

Comment: sorry that was typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xpath 2.0 you should be able to use something like:

```
"//node11[matches(.,'@\d+')]"
```

However, if you aren't using 2.0 you won't have regex support directly. If you are using 1.0 then you won't be able to match using \d+. But this will work:

```
"//node11[contains(.,'@')]"
```

Or even:

```
"//node11[starts-with(.,'@')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
/*/node11[contains(., '@')]
```

**Note**: It is recommended to avoid using the `//` pseudo-operator because this most often leads to very slow evaluation of the XPath expression.

Comment: THANKS, but the above code I wrote is just for example, my problem is to check whether '@' is present or not.

Comment: @dinsolani: Sure. Does my answer provide the wanted information?

Comment: It's not always the case that using `//` is less efficient than full path. In Berkeley DB XML it's explicitly recommended to use `//` instead of a path expression.

Comment: @vanje: Sure, and on the moon one weighs 6 times less.